# apple-mobile-web-app-capable doesn't open in safari

Tags: ios, mobile, ios8, mobile-safari

Noticed this in iOS8 today and I'm not sure if this has always been the case or if it is something that's come in with iOS8.

My company's website, if I save the page to my home screen, adds the icon as expected. But when you open it, it doesn't open in safari, it opens as it's own standalone app. For example, double tapping the home button will show this app open, operating independently of safari.

I gather it has something to do with the `apple-mobile-web-app-capable` meta tag. Can anybody confirm if this is new or if it has always been the case. Also, some insight as to whether the above meta tag is actually responsible for this. Documentation specifies the default is to open in Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the apple-mobile-web-app-capable meta tag will do this and it has been around for several iOS versions.

See more here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW2

Comment: Jeez, I was on that very page I'm sure. Don't know how I missed it. Thanks!